# Understanding matrix transformations for skeletal animation

Tags: matrix, skeletal-animation

I am working with Collada and GLTF.

Say I have a humanoid with 3 bones with the following hierarchy: `B0(root) → B1 → B2`.

**Terminology:**

- bind pose is the same thing as rest pose. If my model is in T-Pose, they both designate bones in T-Pose.
- IBM is inverse bind matrix;
- ILM is inverse local matrix;
- BSM is bind shape matrix;
- LM is local matrix,
- WM is world matrix.

**For animated models**:

Getting the world position of B2 means:

```
WM = B0.matrix; // same as multiply by identity matrix

for (auto &&x : bones){

   auto & LM = x.matrix; 

   WM = LM * WM; // in that order

}
```

Now WM has the world position of B2.

Note I didn't use IBM, because I want the position of the bone at this keyframe in the animation. If I want the Joint transform space,  I should zero out the translation part of the matrix ,  I need to do IBM(B2) * WM;

Now my bone is expressed in relation to its own movement.

I am not sure what to do with BSM, it only seems to scale my model.

From there, If I want to go back to my WM(B2) matrix: I should get the inverse of the IBM(B2) and multiply.

If I want to move the position of the bone WM(B2) and store its new position in gltf or collada, I should do:

```
WM(B2).translationZ = Z;

WM(B2).translationX = X;
```

then take the inverse of each local matrix on the chain:

```
for (auto &&x : bones){

   auto & ILM = inverse(x.matrix); 

   WM = ILM * WM; // in that order

}
```

Now WM should be renamed LM because we have the new local matrix of B2.

**Question**

So, I am not sure I get the logic right and I need someone to tell me if I forgot something, correct me if I am wrong because no source code yields the same results from the same data.

Also, there are different sources that talk about bind pose being different than rest pose, some say they are the same, so please correct my terminology as well if you can.

Comment: When you run the code you've written with this understanding, do you get your desired result? If not, how does the result differ from what you expect? Generally, a StackExchange question should be one that cannot be answered "Yes" or "No" but has some "how" component.

Comment: Yes but there is a known background related to this. I mean, there is only one way to do it and I want to confirm that I didn't forget anything. I give part of the how. Maybe it needs to be completed. Should I post it on SO instead?

Comment: No, they have the same guidelines against yes-or-no questions as we do. Is there any specific aspect of this you're particularly concerned may be wrong? What leads you to that belief? Is there a particular bit you find confusing that you'd like explained? This can help get richer answers than just "Yes" (which wouldn't pass our minimum character count requirement to post).

Comment: @DMGregory: yes, I am not sure I get the logic right, because even trying to compare what game engines do, leads to different results but same visual animation. So I am left in the dust. I will change the question right now to make it more open